# InvalidParameterValue: Unknown template parameter: JVMOptions

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to set encoding to my Java application on the AWS.

I have the following in my `environment.config` file:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
      option_name: JVM Options
      value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

However, when I deploy the app to the cloud, I get the error status in AWS:

```
2016-10-05 09:07:13 UTC+0200    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
2016-10-05 09:07:13 UTC+0200    ERROR   InvalidParameterValue: Unknown template parameter: JVMOptions
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when used the namespace `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions` because I have realized that I was not using tomcat on my Elastic Beanstalk (Spring Boot).

**Try using** `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` instead.

As it is described:

> Note You can extend the number of parameters and specify the parameter
>   names in the aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions and
>   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment namespaces.

In this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It worked perfectly for me. I hope it also worked for the OP. It's a shame no feedback was provided :)

Comment: One thing to add. I named the file env.config inside the .ebextensions as per this repository https://github.com/awslabs/eb-java-scorekeep/tree/master/.ebextensions